# Font not working on my page

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

I can't figure out why my font isn't applied.

I'm trying to apply the "Kenyancoffee" font for classes font1, font2, font3.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<content>
    <div class="font1">
         <p>Text to show up</p>
    </div>
</content>

</article>

<article class="middlecontent"> 
    <header>
        <h2>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this POST TITLE">Our Product</a>
        </h2>
    </header>

    <content>
         <div class="font2">
             <p>Text to show up</p>
         </div>
    </content>

</article>

<article class="bottomcontent">
    <header>
        <h2>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to this POST TITLE">Contact Us</a>
        </h2>
    </header>


    <content>
         <div class="font3">
             <p>Text to show up</p>
         </div>
    </content>

    <style>

        @font-face {
            font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular; 
            src: url(Madmonkey/kenyancoffee.ttf);
        }    

        .font1, .font2, .font3 {
            font-family: KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular;  
        }

   </style>
```

Looking for a mistake for several hours. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, is the font url ok? could be that.
Try inspect element and see if the path is the right one.

```
src: url(Madmonkey/kenyancoffee.ttf);
```

EDIT 2: 
In the HTML are IDs, so #font1, not .font2 (. is for class name and # for ID)
Try with this to see how's working.

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular'; 
  src: url(Madmonkey/kenyancoffee.ttf);
}


     #font1, #font2, #font3 {
      font-family: 'KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular';  
 }
```

Comment: can you post the URL or upload all the files on a server?

Comment: In the CSS you have:  .font1, .font2.... you are giving style to the class, but in the HTML font1, font2... are IDs, so the css must look like this '#font1, #font2, #font3 {
      font-family: 'KenyanCoffeeRg-Regular';  
 }'

Comment: Let me upload all the files with the changes ;)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use kenyan coffe font download the zip from here

http://www.dafont.com/kenyan-coffee.font

and follow the instruction given in text file included in zip